# Change variable value from another file to a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, typeerror

I have a file called `player py`, that contains the variable `player_weapon = items.WBrokenSword`. `items.WBrokenSword` stands for this:

```
class Weapon(Item):
def __init__(self, desc, name, usable, value, damage):
    super().__init__(desc=desc,
                     name=name,
                     usable=usable,
                     value=value)
    self.damage = damage

def __str__(self):
    return "\n{}\n{}\nValue: {}\nDamage: {}\n".format(self.name, self.desc, self.value, self.damage)

class BrokenSword(Weapon):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(name="Espada Danificada",
                         desc="Uma espada pouco resistente.",
                         value=1,
                         usable=0,
                         damage=1)
WBrokenSword = BrokenSword()
```

And in `combat.py`, I have this:

```
player_damage = player.player_weapon.damage
enemy_health -= player_damage
```

This works fine. And in `inventory.py`, I have this:

```
Inv = [items.WRustySword]
print(Inv)
invaction = input("Which item do you want to use?")
intaction = int(invaction)
player.equip(intaction)
```

`player.equip()` means:

```
def equip(what)
    import inventory
    player_weapon = inventory.Inv[what]
    return player_weapon  # just for testing
```

It returns the right information (`WRustySword` is just like `WBrokenSword` but with different numbers), but I get this error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Rusty Sword
```

I've been trying to fix this for 2 days, I even changed the code several times, searched in the internet, and nothing worked. How can I make `player.player_weapon` be `items.WRustySword`? I hope that I gave enough info, but I can always give more if you need to.

Comment: Just FYI you should not import inside of a function.

Comment: Also, what value are you passing into `equip`?

Comment: `intaction`, that is an index of `Inv` in this case, it's `WRustySword`.

Comment: Just to make sure, the error occurs in `player_weapon = inventory.Inv[what]`?

Comment: Yes, it does @HyperNeutrino.